# filter rows within groups after group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like below. Some of the subject/variable group do not have `D1` in `visit`. What I need to do is filter those rows. In other word, I need to extract only those groups that contains `D1` in `visit`.  Appreciate it if anyone can help with this.

```
dt = expand.grid(subject=1:3,
                 variable = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                 visit = c('D1', 'D2', 'D3'))
dt <- dt %>% filter(!(variable=='C'&visit=='D1'))

dt %>% 
    group_by(subject, variable) %>% 
    arrange(subject, variable) %>%
    ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
dt %>% 
   group_by(subject, variable) %>% 
   filter('D1' %in% visit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any`:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(subject, variable) %>% 
  filter(any(visit=="D1"))
```